# How can I show my navbar in collapse when there's a line-break?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar that can be long link titles they can be max 25 characters and the can be 2 to 6 links.

I've made media queries to reduce the size of the font (to a minimum of 10px because less than that it's unreadable) and the padding of the links to compress the navbar until it's in the collapse form to avoid any line breaks but there's so much compressing you can do until it looks bad or line breaks.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1479px){
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-size:calc(10px + 0.1vw);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1327px){
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-size:calc(10px + 0.1vw);
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px){
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-size:calc(10px + 0.1vw);
        padding-left: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
    }
}
```

This is how my navbar looks in it's full width.
[image]

This is how it looks compressed.
[image]

But if it goes any smaller than 1220px it line breaks. 
[image]

So my question is, How can I put it in the collapse form like this when there's a line break:
[image]

Comment: Better use em instead of px to calc font-size

Comment: Because 10px is the minimum before it becomes unreadable. I want that to be my minimum